# Should every pointer in C be allocated on the heap?

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory

Is it required, or recommended, that every pointer in C be allocated on the heap? For example, is it likely or possible that the following code could produce a segmentation fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int* p;
    *p = 16;

    printf("Pointer p = %d\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, pointers can point to anything. It's very common to use pointers to non-heap data.

Comment: For instance, you could use `strtok()` to parse a string that's in a local array.

Comment: But every pointer has to be initialized to point to a valid address before you dereference.

Comment: @Barmar Gotcha, appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will likely segfault because `p` is uninitialized and therefore doesn't point to a valid address.

A pointer doesn't necessarily have to point to heap memory.  It just needs to point to a valid object.  For example:

```
int x = 4;
int *p = &x;
*p = 5;
printf("x=%d\n", x);  // prints 5
```

Comment: When I set ```*p=16```, what happens it memory? Why does ```*p``` sit outside of program memory?

Comment: @MikeLowrey In you code the value of the pointer `p` is *indeterminate*.  The value it contains most likely doesn't point to valid memory, so attempting to dereference the pointer will probably trigger a segfault.  Even if it doesn't, you're modifying memory you shouldn't be.

Comment: I understand now, and I appreciate you help! Would I be right in assuming that the reason why the code still runs without throwing a segmentation fault at me is just because of pure luck?

Comment: @MikeLowrey Yes, that's called [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to be allocated. You just need to make sure it points to valid memory address, which you didn't in your example.

Since you didn't initialize the pointer, it has some random value and trying to dereference it will interpret this value as a memory address, which is probably going to give you a segmentation fault.

You could instead do something like:

```
int x; // not initialized, random value in memory
int *p = &x;
*p = 16; //now you are accessing a valid address (x's)
```